# How to use cmath functions like div in C++?

Tags: c++, cmath

I am new to C++ and I am not sure how to use some of the cmath functions like div.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n < 10) {
        cout << div(n , 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div

Comment: About terminology: `div` is a function; `/` is an operator.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I have looked into this web-site, but despite the fact that I use the same syntax, this solution doesn't work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That link's for `div` in C, for C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

Comment: What do you expect to see from `cout << div(n, 2)` come out and what, exactly, makes you believe that. Please be specific. What is your understanding what `div()` returns, and how do you expect it to be shown on `cout`.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep the C and C++ versions are pretty much the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `cout << div(n , 2)` doesn't work is because `div` doesn't return a number, instead `div` returns a struct with 2 values in there, `quot` and `rem`.

So when you use `div(10, 3)`, it will returns a object with `.quot == 3` and `.rem == 1`.

To print the result of `div`, you would need to first store the result, then print each members separately:

```cpp
auto result = std::div(10, 3);
std::cout << "Quot: " << result.quot << '\n';
std::cout << "Rem: " << result.rem << '\n';
```